# Передача значения поля привязки в шаблон в качестве параметра

Tags: c#, wpf

```
/// <summary>
/// DataGrid со столбцом из CheckBox
/// </summary>
public class CheckBoxDataGridControl : BaseDataGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Имя поля для привязки столбцов с CheckBox
    /// </summary>
    public string ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// CheckBox заголовка
    /// </summary>
    private CheckBox HeaderCheckBox { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструктор
    /// </summary>
    public CheckBoxDataGridControl()
    {
        // Шаблон для строк
        FrameworkElementFactory frameworkRowElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBoxRowTemplate));
        DataTemplate dataRowTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataRowTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkRowElementFactory;
        frameworkRowElementFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(RowCheckBox_OnClick));

        // Шаблон для заголовка
        FrameworkElementFactory frameworkHeaderElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBoxHeaderTemplate));
        DataTemplate dataHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataHeaderTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkHeaderElementFactory;
        frameworkHeaderElementFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HeaderCheckBox_OnClick));
        frameworkHeaderElementFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(HeaderCheckBox_OnLoaded));

        // Добавляем столбец
        DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate = dataRowTemplate;
        dataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate = dataHeaderTemplate;
        Columns.Add(dataGridTemplateColumn);

        // Событие для блокировки записей
        LoadingRow += DataGridWithDisableRows_LoadingRow;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click по CheckBox заголовка
    /// </summary>
    private void HeaderCheckBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemsSource != null)
        {
            // Отмечаем/снимаем флажок только для незаблокированных записей
            foreach (TableObject tableObject in ItemsSource)
                if (!tableObject.IsDisable)
                    tableObject.IsAction = (bool) HeaderCheckBox.IsChecked;
            // Обновить записи
            Items.Refresh();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click по CheckBox строки
    /// </summary>
    private void RowCheckBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetHeaderFromContent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка CheckBox заголовка
    /// </summary>
    private void HeaderCheckBox_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        SetHeaderFromContent();

        // Если блокированы все строки, то блокируем и заголовок
        if(ItemsSource != null)
            if (ItemsSource.Cast<TableObject>().ToList().All(x => x.IsDisable))
                HeaderCheckBox.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Установить состояние CheckBox заголовка в зависимости от состояний CheckBox строк
    /// </summary>
    public void SetHeaderFromContent()
    {
        if (ItemsSource != null)
        {
            List<TableObject> enableTableObjects = ItemsSource.Cast<TableObject>().ToList().FindAll(x => !x.IsDisable);
            if (!enableTableObjects.Any())
                HeaderCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
            else
                HeaderCheckBox.IsChecked = enableTableObjects.All(x => x.IsAction);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Шаблон для CheckBox строки
    /// </summary>
    public class CheckBoxRowTemplate : CheckBox
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор
        /// </summary>
        public CheckBoxRowTemplate()
        {
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Binding binding = new Binding("IsAction");
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, IsCheckedProperty, binding);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Шаблон для CheckBox заголовка
    /// </summary>
    public class CheckBoxHeaderTemplate : CheckBox
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Конструктор
        /// </summary>
        public CheckBoxHeaderTemplate()
        {
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка записей
    /// </summary>
    private void DataGridWithDisableRows_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataContext is TableObject)
        {
            TableObject tableObject = (TableObject) e.Row.DataContext;
            e.Row.IsEnabled = !tableObject.IsDisable;
        }
    }
}
```

Привязка Checked в конструкторе CheckBoxRowTemplate() всегда постоянна IsAction. Как сделать так, чтобы название поля привязки было непостоянным и передавалось значением из поля ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName

Comment: Напишите сеттер для `ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName` делающий то что вам нужно.

Comment: Не понял. Можно пример?

Comment: Пример: https://pastebin.com/1rb8be5h

Comment: а в конструктор CheckBoxRowTemplate как этот сеттер передать?

Comment: Хм, что-то странное вы делаете, можете подробнее описать задачу и показать скрин того что делаете? Может быть привязку надо тоже устанавливать через frameworkRowElementFactory, а не в конструкторе?

Comment: >> Может быть привязку надо тоже устанавливать через frameworkRowElementFactory, а не в конструкторе?
Как вариант можно и через frameworkRowElementFactory, но что-то до меня не доходит как это сделать

Comment: У него есть же метод `SetBinding`

Comment: >> Хм, что-то странное вы делаете, можете подробнее описать задачу
Я делаю свой контрол: DataGrid с CheckBox в заголовке первого столбца с CheckBox-ами, который работает по определённой логике. Раньше всегда привязывалось по полю IsAction, теперь потребовалось, чтобы можно было привязывать столбец к разным полям, т.е. задавать имя поля в xaml. Я создал поле ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName в классе-наследнике DataGrid, а вот как привязать CheckBox пока у меня нет вариантов

Comment: Вам нужно выносить логику из конструктора в сеттер ActionCheckBoxColumnFieldName в любом случае. Вы же понимаете, что пользователь имеет полное право менять это свойство во время работы контрола; да и вообще может его не установить. Другое решение - делать это свойство только для чтения и передавать его значение в конструктор.

Comment: SetBinding есть. А что указывать в качестве DependencyObject? В конструкторе frameworkRowElementFactory же просто тип указывается CheckBoxRowTemplate, а не объект

Comment: Внимательнее смотрите сигнатуру: `FrameworkElementFactory.SetBinding (DependencyProperty, BindingBase)` Но прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий сначала.